# Intel 64/ IA32 Packed Horizontal ADD for Quadwords?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

I am looking for an instruction like PHADDD just for Quadwords.
PHADDQ does not exist, is there some instruction like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`phaddd` is no faster than 2 shuffles + a vertical add, so it's only worth considering when you're using 2 separate inputs.

If you were planning to use it with both inputs the same, just use `pshufd` to copy+swap into another vector.  (Or if you just want a scalar [horizontal sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86), even `movhlps` can be worth considering to extract the high 64 bits into another register.)

---

To fully emulate `phaddq`, you just need two shuffles to take your `A B` and `C D` inputs and give you `A C` and `B D` vectors you can add to get A+B and C+D elements.  That's what [`punpcklqdq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/punpcklbw:punpcklwd:punpckldq:punpcklqdq) and `punpckhqdq` do.  (unpack quad to dq)